# How to use / install NVIM nightly version correctly? (Issue with PlugInstall not working in 0.5 [but will work in 0.4.4])

Tags: nvim

I have scoured the internet trying to figure out how to get NVIM nightly (0.5) running correctly. The furthest I've been able to get is downloading the appimage, putting it into my bin directory, and calling it with:

```
sudo nvim.appimage
```

This allows me to run 0.5, however I can't manage to get Plugins working properly. I have a feeling this has to do with 0.5 being an appimage, because when I call PlugInstall inside of 0.4.4 NVIM it works fine. When I do the same in the nvim.appimage it gives me:

```
E492: Not an editor command: PlugInstall
```

It may be worth noting that I am running Manjaro as my OS. The configuration I'm trying to use uses Lua, so regular NVIM / VIM won't do the trick. I apologize for my inexperience, I have never met another human being who has even heard of VIM much less NVIM nightly. I would source the documentation I followed but I can't seem to find it.. Again I apologize.

On a side note does anyone have any idea when 0.5 will be released (at least as the standard installation)? I dream of the day I can set up NVIM as fast as I can regular ol' vanilla VIM.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think PlugInstall is provided by a plugin manager like vundle or vim-plug; do you perhaps have that installed (or not) somewhere?

Comment: Indeed, his is a [vimplug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) command. Perhaps the image you used to have did bundle this plugin and the new one does not. Installing it via the instructions in the link should resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes I installed vim-plug. Again it works with 0.4.4 (when I type nvim), but not 0.5 ( when I type nvim.appimage). I am able to use both 0.4.4 and 0.5 (via the app image), and just switching between them is the difference between vim-plug working. Sorry if I didn't word this well I'm afraid I'm not very articulate when it comes to this kind of thing

Comment: It might be time to ask the nvim developers if there's some fundamental difference. Only think I can think of is `:scriptnames` and `:verbose set rtp?`

Comment: Ben Knoble, I am actually getting much different results from 0.4.4 and 0.5 by using :scriptnames. I think we are getting close to the problem here. In 0.4.4 all the folder paths are set correctly (I can see the folders/ directories I made for my plug in magager, plugins settings etc). 0.5 shows something much different. I wish I could copy and paste what it says, but basically the appimage has more lines and they are all linked to the tmp folder. I think we are getting close here

Comment: May be able to get specific neovim guidance via the subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim